# How to parse a Flash Date string with .NET?

Tags: .net, datetime, formatting

I am receiving a Flash datetime in the following format:
Sun Jul 17 20:43:02 GMT-0600 2011

The default DateTime.Parse method does not recognize it as a valid datetime.  Is there a way to parse it to get a valid UTC DateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact format for this example would be the following

```
var d = "Sun Jul 17 20:43:02 GMT-0600 2011";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zz'00' yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the parse methods on the `DateTime` class that take a format, they are more flexible in reading dates that follow different formats. See if something along these lines works (feel free to change the format):

```
// Parse date and time with custom specifier.
string dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
string format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
try {
   DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

More examples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx